# Filtering data with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, filter

How do or can I create a filter for all of the members because right now I have about 50 members but the page only display 25 of them due to pagination. As the page only contains 25 member's data, I'm not sure if I can make a filter because the filtered search may be in the other 25 data not being fetch yet. Thanks in advance

**Component**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border border-dark text-center" placeholder="Find someone ...">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)" class= "card col-md-2 col-4 m-3 p-0" v-for="member in members" v-bind:key="member.id">
        <a :href="`#${member.alias_name}`" @click="openModal(member)">
        <img class="card-img-top" :src="getImgFile()">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text text-white text-center">{{member.alias_name}}</p>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**Methods**

```
fetchMembers(page_url){
   let vm=this;
   page_url=page_url || '/api/members/fetchMembers'
   fetch(page_url).then(res=>res.json()).then(res=>{
    this.members = res.data;
    vm.makePagination(res.meta,res.links);
   })
   .catch(err=>console.log(err));
},
makePagination(meta,links){
   let pagination={
      current_page:meta.current_page,
      last_page:meta.last_page,
      next_page_url:links.next,
      prev_page_url:links.prev
   }
  this.pagination = pagination;
},
```

**Controllers**

```
public function fetchMembers()
{
    $members = Member::orderBy("id","ASC")->paginate(25);
    return MemberResource::collection($members);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To show more members in to your page just do this, edit this line:

```
public function fetchMembers()
{
    $members = Member::orderBy("id","ASC")->paginate(100);//<----- 100 per page
    return MemberResource::collection($members);
}
```

If the filter work's properly, you have to paginate throughout all filtered objects, my solution just explain how you can expand your paginated list from 25 items to 100.